# How to filter an ActiveRecord query result by comparison to another model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a simple ActiveRecord query along the lines of this:

```
similar_changes = Notification.where(change_owner: 'foo1', change_target: 'foo2', change_cancelled: false)
```

Each notification object has a field `change_type` and I have another function that checks one Notification's `change_type` with one other Notification for inverse changes (changes that undo each other in the context of my application).

I need to take this Notification's `change_type` and compare it against all others in the array. I have to reference the objects like so: `similar_changes[0]['change_type']` where the first index is each ActiveRecord in the array and the second is the dictionary that specifies which property in the Notification object.

I have a feeling I could do this manually with two nested loops and if statements, but I also know Ruby and I feel like this is something that it should have built in.

Am I wrong, or is there a better way to do this?

Here is the code (note all this code isn't quite finished so bear with me if it's not perfect):

```
def self.group_similar_changes(owner, target, change_type)
  # long query where it selects all rows where change_owner and change_target 
  # are the same as original        
  # also where cancelled is false
  # determine if cancelled (yaml)
  # if cancelled (do nothing)
  similar_changes = Notification.where(
    change_owner: owner, 
    change_target: target, 
    change_cancelled: false
  )
  similar_changes.each do |change|
    cancel_inverse_change(change, change.change_type)
      if change.cancelled?
        similar_changes.delete(change)
      end
    end
  end
end

def cancel_inverse_change(change, change_type)
  if change.inverse?(change_type)
    change.cancel
  end
end

def inverse?(possible_inverse_change)
  is_inverse = false
  change_types = YAML.load_file(File.join(NotificationManager::Engine.root, 'config/change_types.yaml'))
  if self.change_type == change_types[possible_inverse_change]['inverse']
    is_inverse = true
  end
  return is_inverse
end
```

Comment: No, there is no Ruby magic for doing this. Use loops.

Comment: Where is the "inverse" coming from in "return inverse"?
also change_types vs. change_type

Comment: Ah, sorry. That's a typo, sorry.

Comment: You don't need to assign to is_inverse and then return.

just return self.change == change_type[possible_inverse_change][1]['inverse']

(i assume the change_type vs. change_types is also a typo?)

Comment: Unrelated, but you may want to clean up this method by replacing every line except the YAML load with `return self.change == change_type[possible_inverse_change][1]['inverse']`

Comment: I'm aware it needs clean up, and I appreciate the feedback, but it is outside of the scope of the question :). I'm an old java programmer so a few habits die hard

Comment: The line that compares the two changes goes like this: take the current change_type (self.change_type) and compare it to the next change_type. If the current change_type is the inverse of possible_inverse_change, then return true.

Comment: So are you only comparing the current change to each other change once? Why would this need two loops, why not just a loop through similar_changes once, or, possibly better yet, do a single db query and let SQL handle the iteration? `where(change_type: inverse_change_type).present?`

Comment: Andrew Schwartz, the inverse function is just a singular case. In the controller, I have a loop that passes each change to this function

Comment: It's possible that you can do what you want with one of Ruby Enumerable/Array's many methods that loop for you, but we can't really answer your question because you're not showing what you actually want to do. Please add the loop(s) you're talking about to the question.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I will in just a moment!

Comment: I posted the loop for everything in this operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your loop over `similar_changes` can be improved.

- It's confusing to modify the array you're looping over. I don't even know if it's reliable, because I never do it!
- It's also not idiomatic Ruby to rely on the return value of `each`. `each` is normally used to do something to the elements of an Enumerable that already exists, so using its return value seems strange.

I'd write it as

```
similar_changes.reject do |change|
  cancel_inverse_change(change, change.change)
  change.cancelled?
end
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the reject method removes the element if it's T/F?

Comment: Yes, `reject` drops elements for which the block returns true.

Comment: awesome, I'll work these into my code and if I can get it to work well, I'll select the answer. Thank you very much for your feedback :).

Comment: I ended up not doing exactly this, but it did point me in the right direction. I ended up using the Enum map function + this to do the looping and the recursion